# CUDA 6.5 with g++ does not support c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda

I read it here that CUDA 6.5 has started support for C++11 :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thrust-users/R37GIkMG4tk

But when I compile an example code below, I got

$ nvcc -std=c++11 cu-gcc11.cu -o test

nvcc warning : The -c++11 flag is not supported with the configured host compiler. Flag will be ignored.

cu-gcc11.cu(7): error: explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)

My setting : CUDA 6.5, g++ 4.5, ubuntu 12.04

Codes :

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>

__host__ void test() {
  float a = 12.;
  double b = 3.;
  auto c = a * b;
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Upgrade your gcc maybe? gcc4.5 is pretty old.

Comment: Compiles just fine for me. (CUDA 6.5.12, `g++-4.8.2`, Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Hey guys, i'm fully aware 4.5 is old. In fact, i have gcc-4.6 here but i created a symlink back to 4.5. Isn't it stated in CUDA doc that nvcc doesn't support anything > 4.5?

Comment: It is not stated in "CUDA doc" that nvcc doesn't support anything > 4.5.  In general, for a particular cuda release, the supported configurations are listed in the [getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#system-requirements) (including gcc version support for each config/distro).

Answer (score 5):

C++11 support in nvcc is experimental at this time. In order to properly use it you will need an appropriate configuration. This is not documented anywhere AFAIK, but you should have good results with either Fedora 20 or Ubuntu 14.04, both of which are supported configs for cuda 6.5 and include GCC 4.8.x.

In your case your GCC version is just too old.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Just empirically demonstrated that nvcc has no problem with gcc-4.8.1. So my early fear was unfounded.

Comment: Update: As of CUDA 7 C++11 is officially supported.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `-std=c++11` was available in GCC 4.5. Try `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: Won't work : nvcc fatal:Value 'c++0x' is not defined for option 'std'